# react-scroll library registers unnecessary window properties

Tags: reactjs, react-scroll

When using the React scroll library available here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll, there is a strange behaviour which introduces potential bugs and for which I haven't find a plausible solution yet.

Here is the complete code for reproducing the bug, I will explain it briefly just below the code sample.

```
import { Element } from 'react-scroll'

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setData([
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'JavaScript'},
            {'id': 2, 'name': 'jQuery'}
        ])
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {
                data && data.map(item => 
                    <Element id={item.name} name={item.name} key={item.id}>{item.name} {item.name}</Element>)
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```

It is pretty clean code. I have data state variable consisting of an array of objects which I want to iterate over and print each object's name property inside a div. Instead of div, I am using the `<Element/>` tag which is imported from the react-scroll package so that I can have a scroll spy functionality in the menu which will show the active section as the user scrolls through the page.

Now the issue is that whatever I put in the `id` attribute of this `Element` tag, gets binded to the `window` object. So in this case, `window.JavaScript` will be binded to the concrete DOM element containing the text JavaScript, and `window.jQuery` will be binded to the DOM element containing the text jQuery. Here are screenshots from the JavaScript console:

[image]

And if I click any of these logs, it takes me, clearly, to the respective DOM element:

[image]

This is how I actually found the bug, after binding jQuery to the window object, the imported jQuery library stopped working (don't ask why I use jQuery with React :D). The solution that is working so far is changing `id={item.name}` to `id={item.id}` so binding a number to the `window` object, but still, I wanna know if there is a reason each name is bound to `window` and whether that can be disabled.